# Pandas DataFrame fails with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Creating a pandas DataFrame from List of Dict is failing with

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

I have over 4000K json files and each file contains 1 json row of below format --

```
{"title": "abcWebhome", "creator": "demo", "url": "https://demo.demo.xyz/bin/bin/Gamma/", "body": "#REDIRECT [[Gamma]]", "display_title": "Gamma", "last_modifier": "user1", "modification_date": 1450340923000, "creation_date": 1450340923000, "size": "262", "view_count": 0, "category_list": [], "group_list": []}
```

I need to merge these files into 10 json files for which I thinking to process certain number of files and append the data in a list, create a pandas dataFrame and write it to json using df.to_json. I tested the code on ~30 files and it worked fine.

```py
file_list = glob.glob("*.json")

allFilesDict = {v:k for v, k in enumerate(file_list, 1)}

data = []

for k,v in allFilesDict.items():
    if 1 <= k <= 400000:
        with open(v, 'r') as d:
            data.append(json.load(d))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_json(r'/home/user1/merge/output_1.json', orient='records')
```

With the above code the df creation is failing with --

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

How do I identify the cause of error?
Any other approach can be taken to process such huge files and merging it into 10 files.

Comment: please let me know what is the output of the `data`? `print(data)` and also `print(type(data))`

Comment: You could get that error if one of the json values is returning None.  For example, if your sample data row is assigned to `j`, then `data = [j, None]` will recreate the error. To fix it, try `j = json.load(d);if j: data.append(j)`

Comment: Share the entire stack trace